# How is the best way to write an app.request (get/post) reusable with framework7?

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

How is the best way to write an app.request (get/post) reusable?
In my app I have a lot of request (get/post) and for each task I write something like this…

```
  //GET
  var url = endpoint + 'users/';
  var query = '{"id": "20"}';
  app.request.get(url,
          {keys: key,
           where: query,
           username: username,
           lastname: lastname,
           data: data
          },
          function (data) {

            data = JSON.parse(data);
            ….code....

          }

        //POST

        var url = endpoint + 'users/';
        app.request.post(url,
          {keys: key,
           username: username,
           lastname: lastname,
           data: data
          },
          function (data) {

            data = JSON.parse(data);
            switch(d.response.code)
        {
            case '400': ...code.. break;

            case '200': ...code… break;


           }

          }
```

The two things that change in my request is the type (get or post) and the params(sometimes I have all the params above and sometimes only two)… I’d like to create only one function, but I don’t know how to do it. Sorry for my question, I’m a beginner. Thank you in advance for your help.